# Rewriting a request to a parent directory with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, css, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Doing some local PHP development with WAMP. Routing all requests to index.php, *except* requests for assets like stylesheets and images which are in a parent directory outside the document root. Directories are laid out as below:

```
C:\WAMP\www\
    ↳ mySite
        ↳ public
            ↳ .htaccess
            ↳ index.php
        ↳ assets
            ↳ style
                ↳ desktop.css
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mySite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.css$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ assets/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**mySite.conf**

```
Alias /mySite/ "C:/WAMP/www/mySite/public/"

<Directory "C:/WAMP/www/mySite/public/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Results**

`localhost/mySite/` - returns index.php as expected

`localhost/mySite/style/desktop.css` returns an Internal Server Error

What have I missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Anubhava below answered in another question:

> Just to clarify any web site cannot access files above its DOCUMENT_ROOT folder level.

So I should have set the document root as `mySite/` and routed all requests into `public/` to achieve the same security I was aiming for by making public the document root.

Now that `assets/` is inside the document root, I am able to rewrite asset requests to this directory as I desired in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to looping.

Try this code to fix this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mySite/

RewriteRule ^((?!assets/).+?\.css)$ assets/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\/?$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @anubhava. I may not have been clear in my OP - I want to rewrite a request to a file outside the document root, which I don't think can be done, according to an answer you supplied on another question: `Just to clarify any web site cannot access files above its DOCUMENT_ROOT folder level.`

Comment: Yes anything above your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is not accessible via web.